# Añadir/Editar/Mover/eliminar registros de un calendario

Tags: javascript, html, json

tengo un calendario y necesito saber como poder hacer para añadir, editar, etc... eventos del mismo.

Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar en php y ahi sin problemas hago los formularios con AJAX, pero en este caso no se ni por donde empezar a hacer los formularios. En el calendario las fechas salen de este modo.

Entiendo que sera JSON, no busco que me den la solución pero si si podeis guirame, gracias

```
$(function(){

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2016-01-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2016-01-07',
                    end: '2016-01-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-01-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-01-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2016-01-11',
                    end: '2016-01-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2016-01-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-01-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2016-01-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2016-01-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2016-01-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2016-01-28'
                },
        {
                    title: 'Prueba cita',
                    start: '2019-04-23T07:00:00'
                }
            ]
        });
});
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/12/jquery-fullcalandar-integration-with-php-and-mysql.html

Comment: Gracias me pongo a ello! @DiegoAvila

Comment: Una pregunta, tiene que ser PDO?? yo siempre utilice mysqli @DiegoAvila

Comment: no es obligatorio PDO puedes usar en este caso MYSQLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo yo mismo a la pregunta, gracias a **Diego Avila** que me soluciono donde encontar algo parecido.

Además he puesto algunas traducciones ya que no me funcionaba bien la traducción.

El JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable:true,
      locale: 'es',
      dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
      dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
      monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
      monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
      buttonText: {
        today:    'Hoy',
        month:    'Mes',
        week:     'Semana',
        day:      'Día',
        list:     'list'
      },
      header:{
       left:'prev,next today myCustomButton',
       center:'title',
       right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      events: 'load.php',
      selectable:true,
      selectHelper:true,
      select: function(start, end, allDay)
      {
       var title = prompt("Introduce el nombre del evento");
       if(title)
       {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          toastr["success"]("Evento añadido", "Mensaje");
         }
        })
       }
      },
      editable:true,
      eventResize:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function(){
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         toastr["success"]("Evento editado", "Mensaje");
        }
       })
      },

      eventDrop:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function()
        {
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         toastr["success"]("Evento editado", "Mensaje");
        }
       });
      },

      eventClick:function(event)
      {
       if(confirm("¿Quieres eliminar el evento?"))
       {
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({
         url:"delete.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{id:id},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          toastr["success"]("Evento eliminado", "Mensaje");
         }
        })
       }
      },
      timeFormat: 'H:mm' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
     });
    });
```

Insert.php

```
if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO events
 (title, start_event, end_event)
 VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event)
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end']
  )
 );
}
```

Load.php

```
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start_event"],
  'end'   => $row["end_event"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Update.php

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $query = "
 UPDATE events
 SET title=:title, start_event=:start_event, end_event=:end_event
 WHERE id=:id
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end'],
   ':id'   => $_POST['id']
  )
 );
}
```

Delete.php

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=82.223.13.57;dbname=inmoMAMP', 'root', 'b4s3DTs');
 $query = "
 DELETE from events WHERE id=:id
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':id' => $_POST['id']
  )
 );
}
```